# How do I refactor string resources in strings.xml in Eclipse/ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I'd like to rename 100+ strings in my app (to append com.myapp. to the front of all of them for example), but the refactor menu is grayed out when right-clicking. Any other ways of achieving this? Incidentally, does the new Android studio have this functionality?

I already do know the paste to Excel trick for alphabetizing everything.

Comment: `Alt` + `Shift` + `R`

Comment: Alt + Shift + R does work! Thanks deathember. Didn't occur to me to try it.